# Kafka Connect writes data to non-existing topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

Does Kafka Connect creates the topic on the fly if it doesn't exist (but provided as a destination) or fails to copy messages to it?

I need to create such topics on the fly or programmatically (Java API) at least, not manually using scripts.

I searched this info, but it seems topics have to be already created before migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Connect doesn't really control this.

There's a setting in Kafka that enables/disables automatic topic creation.

If this is turned on - Kafka Connect will create its' own topics, if not - you have to create them yourselves.

Comment: In distributed mode config, it creates 3 topics for storing offsets, configs, and statuses using the AdminClient API, though. Auto topic creation can be disabled, and it'll still work for those topics, just not source connector topics. Not sure if this is only available in recent versions, though

Answer (score 1):

By default, Kafka will not create a new topic when a consumer subscribes to a non-existing topic. you should enable the `auto.create.topics.enable=true`in your **Kafka server configuration file** which enables ***auto-creation*** of topics on the server.

Once you turn on this feature Kafka will automatically create topics on the fly. When an application tries to connect to a non-existing topic, Kafka will create that topic automatically.

Comment: Documentation reference: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_auto.create.topics.enable